# When you hover over one div, chage the style of multiple other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Afternoon,

I need a little help if possible...

As the title explains, when you hover over a div, i want multiple other divs styles to be changed (different colours at the min). i have currently tried using just pure CSS but finding it quite a struggle. [My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3t3spkn/)

As you can see on my JSFiddle, when you hover over the 'red' box, the boxes at either side changes colour to yellow, if you hover over the 'Green' box, it changes colour to yellow, however, if you over over the 'pink' box it changes colour to cyan but also the far left box changes to yellow, which i dont want to happen.

Could anybody help out? I dont mind if i have to use JQuery/Javascript thats not an issue, i just attempted using CSS as i have no knowledge of JQuery/Javascript.

Thank you and i hope it makes sense what i am trying to achieve.

CSS

```
img{width:100%;}
#container{width:100%; float:left;}
.maintest{width:20%; height:150px; background:red; float:left;}
.maintest:hover{background:#f2f2f2;}


.maintest2{width:20%; height:150px; background:green; float:left;}
.maintest2:hover{background:magenta;}
.maintest3{width:20%; height:150px; background:pink; float:left;}
.maintest3:hover{background:cyan;}


#container:hover .maintest2{background:yellow; border-right:solid 1px black;}
.maintest:hover ~ .maintest3{background:yellow}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

<a href="#" class="maintest2">

</a>

 <a class="maintest" href="#"></a>

 <a href="#" class="maintest3"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: yeah, you'll need javascript. plain css cannot do much to make events on one node affect things in cousin/sibling nodes. the plain css rules for such things get extremely ugly extremely quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule #container:hover .maintest2 {} is causing the behavior you *don't* want. But this is also giving you the desired behavior of having the "when I hover over red, it changes the other 2 boxes to yellow.

Like the commenters said, this doesn't look possible without using JS.

Quick jquery to do it:

```
$(".maintest2, .maintest3").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("yellow-background");
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("yellow-background");
});

$(".maintest").hover(function(){
    $(".maintest2, .maintest3").addClass("yellow-background");
}, function(){
    $(".maintest2, .maintest3").removeClass("yellow-background");
});
```

Documentation on hover event: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thats perfect thanks alot! Does exactly what i want it to do! Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mind using jQuery, I will give you a jQuery answer,

```js
$('.box').each(function() {

  //this will iterate through each div with class=box
  $(this).hover(function() {
      //on mouse in
      $(this).attr('data-active-box', 'true');
    },
    function() {
      //on mouse out
      $(this).attr('data-active-box', 'false');
    });

});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box[data-active-box='true'] {
  background-color: green;
}
.box[data-active-box='false'] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='box box1' data-active-box='false'></div>
<div class='box box2' data-active-box='false'></div>
<div class='box box3' data-active-box='false'></div>
```

The js will toggle the data attribute on mouse-in/out. The css will style the div based on the attribute. There's a million ways to do this!